# MATLAB Matrix (Cell Array) Indexing

Tags: matlab, for-loop, matrix, indexing, cell

I have just started learning MATLAB . 
 Please find my codes below

```
m= ['A','B','C'];
cs=size(m,2);
for i=1:cs
    for j=1:cs

            if i~=j
             s1=(m(i));s2=',';s3=(m(j));
                 s=strcat(s1,s2,s3);
                     disp(s);
        end    
    end
end
```

It produces the following output on command window.

```
A,B
A,C
B,A
B,C
C,A
C,B
```

But , i want to wrap up all the outputs into  a single matrix (or Cell Array ) , Lets say new_M .
So that the values of new_M shall contain the all above values like this .

```
new_M (6,1) =
[ A,B 
A,C
B,A
B,C
C,A
C,B ]
```

Your help will be highly appreciatated . Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idiomatic way to do this would be to use `nchoosek` to get the indices you want and then use linear indexing:

```
m = ['A','B','C'] %// For a char array OR
m = {'A','B','C'} %// For a cell array
I = nchoosek(1:numel(m), 2)
new_M = m([I; I(:,end:-1:1)])
```

Comment: Thank a TON  Mr  knedlsepp .

Answer (score 1):

This will work. In 'c' you will find the values

```
    m= ['A','B','C'];
cs=size(m,2);
c = cell(6,1)
t = 1;
for i=1:cs
    for j=1:cs

            if i~=j
             s1=(m(i));s2=',';s3=(m(j));
                 s=strcat(s1,s2,s3);
                 disp(s)
                 c{t} = s;
                 t=t+1;
        end    
    end
end
```

Comment: Thanks a TON Mr Salvatore

Answer (score 1):

```
m= ['A','B','C'];
cs=size(m,2);
new_M = [];
for i=1:cs
    for j=1:cs
        if i~=j
         s1=(m(i));s2=',';s3=(m(j));
         s=strcat(s1,s2,s3);
         new_M = [new_M;s];
        end    
   end
end
```

The `new_M` matrix will contain all the values you need.

Comment: Thanks a TON Mr JNY Ranger and Mr sandy